# Python absolute value on list nested within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Current Dataframe:

   ID       Price   Price_List
0  Prodt1   1500    [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0]
1  Prodt2   17      [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0]
```

and I would like to apply the absolute value to the list in Price_List (except the zero-value), and add it back to itself, then sort it.  The resulting column would be like the below:

```
Desired Dataframe:

   ID       Price   Price_List               New_Col
0  Prodt1   1500    [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0]    [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0, 3.3, 4.6, 5.2]
1  Prodt2   17      [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0]    [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0, 2.1, 8.4, 9.2]
```

Any help is very very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension to iterate over the lists in `Price_List` and extend each list with the absolute values of all elements except `0` with a conditional expression (note that `if j` is enough as the expression will evaluate to `False` only when `j` is `0`):

```
df['New_Col'] = sorted(i + [abs(j) for j in i if j] for i in df.Price_List)
```

---

```
print(df)

     ID    Price         Price_List                    New_Col
0  Prodt1   1500  [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0]  [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0, 3.3, 4.6, 5.2]
1  Prodt2     17  [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0]  [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0, 2.1, 8.4, 9.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` if the data frame is not too large to add the list with a list comprehesion that uses `abs`

```
df['New_Col'] = df.Price_List.apply(lambda x: sorted(x + [abs(xx) for xx in x if x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Series.map` and with `np.abs`, `np.trim_zeros` also work

```
df['New_Col'] = df.Price_List.map(lambda x: sorted(x + 
                                      np.trim_zeros(np.abs(x)).tolist()))

Out[249]:
       ID  Price             Price_List                               New_Col
0  Prodt1   1500  [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0]  [-5.2, -4.6, -3.3, 0, 3.3, 4.6, 5.2]
1  Prodt2     17  [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0]  [-9.2, -8.4, -2.1, 0, 2.1, 8.4, 9.2]
```